# How to let Angular 6 Http Get method returns an array of observable instead of an observable of array?

Tags: angular, observable

Suppose my backend has a route that returns `const list = ['Man United', 'Man City']`, and my Angular 6 has `http.get()` to that route then subscribes with `console.log('team: ' + value)`.

I will get team: `['Man United', 'Man City']` as the result.
Is there a way to convert the observable of array to array of observable? i.e., I want to subscribe with `console.log('team: ' + value')` then I will get team: Man United, team: 'Man City'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and it is actually very easy.

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

getCommands(): Observable<string> {
    return http.get(url).pipe(
        flatMap((commands: string[]) => from(commands))
    )
}
```

PS. This is for current angular 6 version.

Comment: I thought of this too, but would this lower the performance of Angular?

Comment: Any additional line of code lowers the performance. The question is - would you be able to see it if it's 0.001%? You're trying to solve the problem that doesn't exist so far. Solve it _**when**_ it becomes an issue, not _**if**_. Performance of rxjs is pretty good in general, so don't worry about it.